# Javascript switch statement nested inside If statement cannot access other variables and returns Unidentified

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I am working on a Rock/Paper/Scissors game like as usual. Somehow my `if` and `switch` statements cannot read the values set by the other two functions and when I `console.log` `result` it returns `undefined`

However when I manually set `user` and `computer` variables `decideWinner` function works as intended.

I've been tinkering with it for a couple of hours and some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```js
let user
let computer
let result
//1
function userChoice() {
  let user = prompt(`rock, paper, scissors`)
}

//2
function computersTurn() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 1:
      computer = `rock`;
      break;
    case 2:
      computer = `scissors`;
      break;
    case 3:
      computer = `paper`;
      break;
  }
}

//3
function decideWinner() {
  if (user == `rock`) {
    switch (computer) {
      case `rock`:
        result = `tie`
        break;
      case 'scissors':
        result = `player`
        break;
      case `paper`:
        result = `computer`
        break;
    }
  } else if (user == `paper`) {
    switch (computer) {
      case `rock`:
        result = `player`
        break;
      case 'scissors':
        result = `computer`
        break;
      case `paper`:
        result = `tie`
        break;
    }
  } else if (user == `scissors`) {
    switch (computer) {
      case `rock`:
        result = `computer`
        break;
      case 'scissors':
        result = `tie`
        break;
      case `paper`:
        result = `player`
        break;
    }
  }
}

userChoice();
computersTurn();
decideWinner();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: update the `userChoice()` method, remove the `let` keyword

Comment: Take a look at [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return). Rather than changing global variables within your functions (which isn't usually a good idea as it can lead to hard to debug code), you can return the values from your function that you want to set your variables equal to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not recreate the `user` variable. When you do this, another `user` variable is created **locally** and the prompt result is assigned to that variable, hence keeping your global `user` variable undefined. Use `user = ...` instead of `let user = ...`:

```js
let user
let computer
let result
//1
function userChoice() {
  user = prompt(`rock, paper, scissors`)
}

//2
function computersTurn() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 1:
      computer = `rock`;
      break;
    case 2:
      computer = `scissors`;
      break;
    case 3:
      computer = `paper`;
      break;
  }
}

//3
function decideWinner() {
  if (user == `rock`) {
    switch (computer) {
      case `rock`:
        result = `tie`
        break;
      case 'scissors':
        result = `player`
        break;
      case `paper`:
        result = `computer`
        break;
    }
  } else if (user == `paper`) {
    switch (computer) {
      case `rock`:
        result = `player`
        break;
      case 'scissors':
        result = `computer`
        break;
      case `paper`:
        result = `tie`
        break;
    }
  } else if (user == `scissors`) {
    switch (computer) {
      case `rock`:
        result = `computer`
        break;
      case 'scissors':
        result = `tie`
        break;
      case `paper`:
        result = `player`
        break;
    }
  }
}

userChoice();
computersTurn();
decideWinner();
console.log(result);
```

Note: you can rewrite your `computersTurn` function in a simpler way:

```
function computersTurn() {
  let choices = ["rock", "scissors", "paper"];
  let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
  computer = choices[randomNumber];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was so focused on the if statement and the rest.